# get all child elements that are not a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get all children, but skip tables:

What I have is:

```
var allElements = $("body").children();
$.each(allElements, function(i, element)
{
  // Do something
}); // each element
```

Now I look for either a way, that allElements does not include tables or a function, that returns true, if an element is a table:

```
if(element.is("table"));
```

I do not find anything. Does anyone know a solution for this issue?

Comment: what about tbody, tr, td and elements inside those tags? Do you want also exclude them all?

Comment: @Yuriy Rozhovetskiy If I take children of body, those elements are not in this collection, are they?

Comment: Of course not, this was my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) accepts a selector, so use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) one:

```
$('body').children(':not(table)').each(function () {
    // Whatever
});
```

For future reference, you were on the right track with `is()`, but as it returns true if **any** of the elements in the  jQuery object matches the selector, you'd have to use it as follows:

```
$('body').children().each(function () {
    if (!$(this).is('table')) {
        // It isn't a table, do whatever
    }
});
```

To keep providing alternatives, you could also use the [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not) method:

```
$('body').children().not('table').each(function () {
    // Do whatever
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.not()` function like this:

```
$("body").children().not('table');
```

Or, if you want to check as part of a larger expression within the each loop, you can use `is()`, eg.

```
if (! $(this).is('table')) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can do it in a single selector:

```
$('body > :not(table)').each...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').children().each(function(){
    if(!$(this).is('table'))
    alert($(this).html())
})
```

an example here http://jsfiddle.net/S2tUS/

or maybe this

```
$('body').children(':not(table)').each(function(){
    alert($(this).html())
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S2tUS/2/